# FCurve Noise modifier: set "Offset" value using Python

Tags: python, modifiers, fcurves

First of all: excuse me for my terrible english.
Is there any way to set "Offset" value of "Noise" modifier in Graph Editor using Python?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found out this by myself.

```
bpy.data.actions['Compositing NodetreeAction'].fcurves[X].modifiers[Y].offset = Z
```